# confidence interval uniform distribution $U[1,N]$

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood

You have a lottery ticket and it has the number 320 on it. Show  confidence interval for the number of lottery tickets (to $\alpha=0.05$). Assume there are N tickets total numbered 1 to N.

I'm trying to do with inverting a Hypothesis Test

suggestions please

Comment: A good starting point is the Wikipedia article on the [German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem#Confidence_intervals).

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.